# Erlang records printing

Tags: erlang, record

I am writing a program in erlang and I created this record:

```
-record(tree, {node, left, right}).
```

I want to print a list of different trees, and this is how prints it:

```
[{tree,x1,{x3,0,1},{tree,x2,1,{x3,0,1}}}, {tree,x1,{tree,x3,0,1},{tree,x3,{x2,1,0},1}}]
```

Is there an easy to print it without the word "tree"? (the name of the record).
Sure I can just define it as a tuple and not a record, but I want to try to work with a record so the code will be more organized.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Inside shell you can use:

```sh
Eshell V9.1  (abort with ^G)
```

```erlang
1> Trees = [
    {tree, x1, {x3, 0, 1}, {tree, x2, 1, {x3, 0, 1}}},
    {tree, x1, {tree, x3, 0, 1}, {tree, x3, {x2, 1, 0}, 1}}
].

[{tree,x1,{x3,0,1},{tree,x2,1,{x3,0,1}}},{tree,x1,{tree,x3,0,1},{tree,x3,{x2,1,0},1}}]


2> Format = fun({tree, Node, Left, Right}, F) -> 
    {
        Node,
        if 
            element(1, Left) == tree -> F(Left, F);
            true -> Left
        end,
        if
            element(1, Right) == tree -> F(Right, F);
            true -> Right
        end
    }
end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.99386804>

3> [Format(X, Format) || X <- Trees].
[
    {{x3, 0, 1}, {1, {x3, 0, 1}}},
    {{0, 1}, {{x2, 1, 0}, 1}}
]
```

And in your module you can place for example a `format/1` function:

```erlang
-module(tree).

-record(tree, {node, left, right}).

-export([format/1]).


format(#tree{node = Node, left = L, right = R}) ->
    {Node, maybe_format(L), maybe_format(R)};

format([#tree{}=Tree | Trees]) ->
    [format(Tree) | format(Trees)];

format([]) ->
    [].


maybe_format(X) when erlang:is_record(X, tree) ->
    format(X);

maybe_format(X) ->
    X.
```

And use it in shell or wherever you want:

```erlang
Eshell V9.1  (abort with ^G)
```

```erlang
% Compile my module which is inside current directory:
1> c(tree).
{ok,tree}

% format single tree:
2> tree:format({tree, node, left, right}).
{node,left,right}

% format list of trees:
3> tree:format([{tree,x1,{x3,0,1},{tree,x2,1,{x3,0,1}}}, {tree,x1,{tree,x3,0,1},{tree,x3,{x2,1,0},1}}]).

[
    {x1, {x3, 0, 1}, {x2, 1, {x3, 0, 1}}},
    {x1, {x3, 0, 1}, {x3, {x2, 1, 0}, 1}}
]
```